# How to use sessions with MongoEngine and Flask-Login?

Tags: python, oauth, mongoengine, flask-login, rauth

I'm using Flask-Login, MongoEngine, OAuth with Rauth for Flask.

I need to save my user's session in MongoEngine but I don't know how to do it.

My code is that:

```
@app.route('/callback/<provider>')
def oauth_callback(provider):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    social_id, username, email = oauth.callback()
    if social_id is None:
        flash('Authentication failed.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    user = User.objects(social_id=social_id).first()
    if not user:
        user = User(social_id=social_id, nickname=username, email=email)
        user.save()
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    login_user(user, True)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

In code, this lines `db.session.add(user)` and `db.session.commit()` is for SQL but I dont know how do it in MongoEngine.

Is there any way to do it in MongoEngine in a simple way?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have a very similar situation.

Comment: @robster I solved it a long time ago but I used the flask session with `from flask import session` and the usage would be simply like `session[username] = username` for example.
If you need more help don't hesitate to answer me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `user.save()` is doing the job.
Can use `current_user.save()` depending on code.